# vba code to change column formula by dynamic dragging

Tags: excel, vba

i need to write vba code wherein cell GQ4 has formula

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUM(CO4:CQ4)"
```

Now there is new month added every month in excel data hence the formula will also change dynamically every month.
ie next month it will be

```
"=SUM(CP4:CR4)"
```

in short it is dragging its column selection by 1 column

Please help me write a vba code that will dynamically change the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Note sure if it is possible to return a formula from a custom function, but a solution might be to write a custom function that returns the range you want, and then have the formula in GQ4 take the range as an argument.

Or you can solve it with a normal worksheet formula.

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(4;15));INDIRECT(ADDRESS(4;16));INDIRECT(ADDRESS(4;17)))
```

Replace the column numbers with a base + offset that you can get by using a date function. E.g.

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(4;14 + =MONTH(TODAY())));INDIRECT(ADDRESS(4;15 + =MONTH(TODAY())));INDIRECT(ADDRESS(4;16 + =MONTH(TODAY()))))
```